# NCalc missing EOF

Tags: c#, ncalc

i was trying to evaluate expression using NCalc,

```
Expression ex = new Expression("3[X] + 4[Y]");
ex.Parameters["X"] = 10;
ex.Parameters["Y"] = 20;
```

I have been getting this error:

> missing EOF at '[x]' at line 1:1

Not sure why I have getting this error? Does the square brackets for variables have something to do with this?

Comment: I've never used NCalc before, but my guess is that it doesn't support the "nx" multiplication syntax. Try doing `"3 * [X] + 4 * [Y]"` instead.

Comment: That worked. Seriously I missed such a small thing.

Answer (score 1):

See NCalc's [parameters documentation](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=parameters).

Using static parameters:

```
Expression e = new Expression("2 * [x] ^ 2 + 5 * [y]");
e.Parameters["x"] = 5;
e.Parameters["y"] = 1;

Console.WriteLine(e.Evaluate());
```

From your example:

```
Expression ex = new Expression("3 * [X] + 4 * [Y]");
ex.Parameters["X"] = 10;
ex.Parameters["Y"] = 20;

// 110
Console.WriteLine(ex.Evaluate());
```

Comment: Is there a way we could evaluate expression even when multiply(*) is not mentioned in expression like "3[X] + 4[Y]" .Also is there a way we could check the format of expression  ?

Comment: The library doesn't appear to support implicit multiplication. However, you can "build up" expressions if the grammar is too strict for your use case. See [the tests](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Evaluant.Calculator.Tests/Fixtures.cs). You can check expressions for errors using `Expression.HasError` and `Expression.Error`.